# How to Detect Tab Click Event in .NET MAUI AppShell with TabBar and Refresh Page on Tab Re-click

Tags: maui, app-shell

I need to detect tab clicking, for example, when I am on Tab2 and click on Tab2 again, I want to refresh the page, how can I do this? I know that there is no built-in Clicked event for . How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As a summary, I will post a answer so that it will help others who have similar problems.

For this problem, we can try to use the workaround [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15301#issuecomment-2011857836).

The steps are as follows:

1.Override the Shell's `OnNavigating` to trigger `PopToRootAsync` on
Android.

2.Subclass the `ShellRenderer` for Android and register the BottomView's
`ItemReselected` event.  We should register it only once, otherwise we will get multiple events.

```
using Android.Content;
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility;

namespace Your.Namespace;

/// <summary>
/// Shell renderer to fix tab reselection event issue on Android
/// https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15301
/// </summary>
public class AndroidShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public AndroidShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(this, shellItem);
    }
}

public class CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    private readonly IShellContext _shellRenderer;
    private readonly ShellItem _shellItem;
    private bool _subscribedItemReselected;

    public CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellRenderer, ShellItem shellItem)
        : base(shellRenderer, shellItem)
    {
        _shellRenderer = shellRenderer;
        _shellItem = shellItem;
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        if (_subscribedItemReselected) return;
        bottomView.ItemReselected += ItemReselected;
        _subscribedItemReselected = true;
    }

    private void ItemReselected(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (_shellItem as IShellItemController).ProposeSection(_shellItem.CurrentItem);
    }
}
```

3.Register the newly created ShellRenderer as a Handler for the Shell
component

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _isPopToRootInProgress;
    protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);
        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android
            && args.Source == ShellNavigationSource.ShellSectionChanged
            && args is { Current: not null, Target: not null }
            && args.Current.Location == args.Target.Location
            && !_isPopToRootInProgress
            && CurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
        {
            _isPopToRootInProgress = true;
            CurrentPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync().ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                _isPopToRootInProgress = false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Register handler

```
     builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
#if ANDROID
        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(Your.Namespace.AndroidShellRenderer))
#endif
    });
```